# Rendering an MP3 file via a URL using Azure

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-functions

I am using an API that needs an MP3 file via an http endpoint.  Can I render an mp3 via an Azure Function?  I have searched for a tutorial with no luck.  I do not want to create a full VM for such a small use case.

Specifically I am using Twilio to handle phone calls.  The Twilio API will play an mp3 menu to the caller but the mp3 has to be made available to the Twilio API via an http endpoint.

Comment: Please define "an API that needs an MP3 file"

Comment: @CSharpRocks see my edit.  Thanks.

Comment: So your API needs to return a binary file (an MP3 file).  Twilio must have documented the expected format.

Comment: Check out ://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-static-file-server/ which walks you through serving static files from Azure Functions. The specific MIME types supported by the <Play> verb are here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#nouns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Devin's comment and the post at https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-static-file-server/ should help you build an Azure function to host a file.

However writing all that code just to return an mp3 seems like a waste to me. If you want to keep everything within Azure, then it is probably the way forward for you, but if you don't mind hosting the mp3 elsewhere, can I recommend [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets)? If you open up your Twilio console and head to [Runtime -> Assets](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/assets/public) you will find a simple store where you can put static files to be used in your own applications.

Hope this helps.